# C# - How do I deserialize json from Azure DevOps Work Item List?

Tags: c#, api, serialization, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

Working on pulling work items from Azure Devops:

According to this article, the response looks like so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

```
{
   "count": 2,
   "value": [
     {
       "id": 297,
       "rev": 1,
       "fields": {
          "System.AreaPath": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
          "System.Title": "Customer can sign in using their Microsoft Account",
          ...
       }
     },
     {
       "id": 298,
       "rev": 1,
       "fields": {
          "System.AreaPath": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
          "System.Title": "Customer can log out",
          ...
       }
     }
    ]
}
```

I am assuming that an object for it would look something like this:

```
public class WorkItemModel
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public int rev { get; set; }
   public FieldsModel fields { get; set; }
}

public class FieldsModel
{
   public string AreaPath { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

But how do I deserialize this into the proper objects? And how does the "System.AreaPath" and "System.Title" get handled?

Comment: In `Newtonsoft.Json`, you can add the `JsonProperty` attribute to the property so it would look like `public class FieldsModel { [JsonProperty("System.AreaPath")] public string AreaPath {get; set;} ...`

Comment: looks like there are packages available which contain the models you will need: [azure-devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

You can create Models as below:

```
public class FieldsModel
{
    [JsonProperty("System.AreaPath")]
    public string SystemAreaPath { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.Title")]
    public string SystemTitle { get; set; }
}

public class WorkItemModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int rev { get; set; }
    public FieldsModel fields { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<WorkItemModel> value { get; set; }
}

//using as below
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```